# How can we avoid redundant interface implementation?

Tags: c#, architecture, interface

I have a design question. 
I shall present a hypothetical situation.
I have a couple of interfaces required by my application to make an object usable. Let’s say they are;

```
1.  IAdult.cs, with two properties
  a.    Age
  b.    LicenceNo.
2.  IEducated.cs, with two methods
  a.    Read()
  b.    Write()
```

Let’s assume that the implementation of these interfaces shall remain the same most of the times. So, if we had to implement an abstract class out of these interfaces, we could simply create a class, say, abstract class EducatedAdult {  }.
Now we define three different classes with their respective inheritances and a set of respective properties;

```
1.  Carpenter.cs (derives from class A)
2.  Plumber.cs (derives from class B)
3.  Programmer.cs (derives from class C)
```

Here, the classes A, B, C are part of some external libraries that I cannot edit. Now to make these objects usable in the Program, they need to implement the above given interfaces. So the issue is that for each one of these classes, I’ll have to explicitly implement the above stated interfaces. Could there be a better design where I do not have to implement the interfaces redundantly in all the classes. This could be a solution, had it been possible;

Class `EducatedAdult<t>: t, IAdult, IEducated { <implementation of interfaces> }`
And later, maybe, I could just initialize my derived classes like;

`Carpenter carpenter = new EducatedAdult<Carpenter>()`. Not that this would be an ideal solution, ‘cause the public interface of the carpenter object shall still not include my interface members (without required casting). But then, what could be the most suitable design?

Comment: can't  you provide implementation in the Educated Adult Class? If abstraction won't let you, don't define it as abstract?

Comment: looks like you need a base class for Carpenter, Plumber and Programmer, and EducatedAdult seems to be that one. you don't have to implement IAdult and IEducated interfaces in each of these derived types that you mentioned

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited my question to complete the missing parts. The carpenter class already derives from another class. Sorry!

Comment: This looks like the most suitable  solution for me (solution 3 by Nishant, on the link page below);

[http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/189308/How-can-we-avoid-redundant-interface-implementatio.aspx#answer3](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/189308/How-can-we-avoid-redundant-interface-implementatio.aspx#answer3)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really provide default implementations for Interfaces in .NET its just up to the implementing class to provide the implementation, but you can fake it using extension methods on Interfaces.

Comment: You can definitely do it in .NET, just not in C#.

Comment: There is a good example that someone suggested in another forum. It implements your suggestion. And to some extent it does make sense to me. [Base Implementations for Interfaces using Extension Methods](http://netvignettes.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/base-implementations-for-interfaces-using-extension-methods/). But honestly it still seems like more of a work around. I have to take care of my properties also.

Comment: Hi Jordão, can you explain your comment?

Comment: @Manish Verma: just look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829439/how-can-we-avoid-redundant-interface-implementation/5839305#5839305). I mention 2 .NET languages where this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now that you updated your question:

- Use some kind of mixin approach as outlined here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/C__3_Mixin.aspx
- Use a tool like DynamicProxy to do real mixins: http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2009/08/12/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-xiii-mix-in-this-mix-in-that.aspx

**Update**: The approach with the least amount of work would probably be:

```
public interface IAdult { }
public interface IEducated { }

public static class Extensions
{
    // IAdult extensions
    public static void Age(this IAdult adult)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static void LicenseNo(this IAdult adult)
    {
        ...
    }

    // IEducated extensions
    public static void Read(this IEducated educated)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static void Write(this IEducated educated)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then mark your classes with the empty interfaces so you have nothing to implement

```
public class Carpenter : IAdult, IEducated
{
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
var carpenter = new Carpenter();
carpenter.Read();
```

And if you want to "override" the interface method to provide a different implementation you can do this:

```
public class Carpenter : IAdult, IEducated
{
    public void Read() { ... }
}
```

When you call `Read()` now on a `Carpenter` object it will use the actual `Read()` method from the `Carpenter` class instead of the extension method. You can make it even `virtual` and derive from `Carpenter` and override it in the child class like you used to. In order to call the default implementation of `Read()` in the `Carpenter` object you would have to do `Extensions.Read(this)` instead of `base.Read()`.

Comment: I am sorry, I just edited my question to complete the missing parts. The carpenter class already derives from another class.

Comment: I am looking at your links and a similar one. [http://remix.codeplex.com](http://remix.codeplex.com). I think there could be a solution here.

Comment: I have come back from this approach. This would be too much of an external code for my application. I would rather wade through finding a solution in a better design.

Comment: This is something interesting. I am definately going to try a sample out of this approach. Thanks Chris!

Comment: Hi Chris, the solution you proposed, while it 'looks' elegant, defies the purpose of Design by Contract. Now I find that my interfaces, IAdult or IEducated are actually meaningless. There has to be a better design.

Answer (score 0):

In your case yo should create EducatedAdult as a Class Implement all the common methods for your three classes in EducatedAdult implement as abstract the others and then implement the specific methods on each class.

See you

Comment: I am sorry, I just edited my question to complete the missing parts. The carpenter class already derives from another class.

Comment: I see, the possible solution that you're providing about working with generics is not correct, at least as you assign an instance of EducatedAdult<Carpenter> to a Carpenter. MAybe the solution then should pass through extending A, B and C from the EducatedAdult class I provide in my response.

Comment: The A, B, C classes are part of some external libraries that I cannot edit :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it in C# without some kind of assembly rewriter or without using `dynamic`. You can do something similar to a [mixin](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2011/03/c-mixins-with-state.html), but it would change your design.

If you can use another language, [Oxygene](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Implements_(keyword)) and [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/Design_patterns#Proxy_design_pattern) offer a feature to implement an interface by delegating all its members to some field that also implement the interface.